# Problems in reloading python module from C++ static library being used in Fortran project

Tags: python, c++, fortran

I'm trying to link Fortran|C/C++|Python using VS2010 on Windows 64-bit. I have a main code that is written in Fortran. From that code I call a C++ function and after that I call a Python function to do some staff further. Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
!Fmain.f90
PROGRAM fmain
IMPLICIT NONE
INTERFACE
SUBROUTINE Call_NN(input_array, output_array) BIND(C, name='Call_NN')
USE, INTRINSIC :: iso_c_binding
IMPLICIT NONE
REAL(C_DOUBLE), INTENT(IN), DIMENSION(*) :: input_array
REAL(C_DOUBLE), INTENT(INOUT), DIMENSION(*) :: output_array
END SUBROUTINE
END INTERFACE

REAL*8, DIMENSION(0:2) :: input_array, output_array
REAL :: b
INTEGER :: i

do i = 1, 3
input_array = 0.01d0
output_array = 0.d0
call Call_NN(input_array, output_array)
enddo

END
```

The C++ static library is as following:

```
//Csub.cpp
#include <Python.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <array>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


extern "C" void Call_NN(array<double,3> input_array, array<double,3> output_array)
    {    
        // Initialize the Python interpreter.
        Py_Initialize();

        // Variables Declaration
        float result  = 0; 
        float result1 = 0;
        float result2 = 0;
        float result3 = 0;
        float value1  = 0;
        float value2  = 0;
        float value3  = 0;

        // Create some Python objects that will later be assigned values.
        PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pArgs, *pValue1, *pValue2, *pValue3;
        PyObject *pT1, *pT2, *pT3;

        // Convert the file name to a Python string.
        const char* filename = "module"; 
        pName = PyString_FromString(filename); 
        if (pName == nullptr)
        {
            PyErr_Print();
            std::exit(1);
        }

        // Import the file as a Python module.
        pModule = PyImport_Import(pName); 
        if (pModule == nullptr)
        {
            PyErr_Print();
            std::exit(1);
        }

        // Create a dictionary for the contents of the module.
        pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
        if (pDict == nullptr)
        {
            PyErr_Print();
            std::exit(1);
        }

        // Get the add method from the dictionary.
        pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "NN");
        if (pFunc == nullptr)
        {
            PyErr_Print();
            std::exit(1);
        }

        // Create a Python tuple to hold the arguments to the method.
        pArgs = PyTuple_New(3);
        if (pArgs == nullptr)
        {
            PyErr_Print();
            std::exit(1);
        }

        // Convert 3 to a Python integer.
        value1 = input_array[0];
        value2 = input_array[1];
        value3 = input_array[2];
        pValue1 = PyFloat_FromDouble(value1);
        pValue2 = PyFloat_FromDouble(value2);
        pValue3 = PyFloat_FromDouble(value3);

        // Set the Python int as the first and second arguments to the method.
        PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue1);
        PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, pValue2);
        PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 2, pValue3);

        // Call the function with the arguments.
        PyObject* pResult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);

        // Print a message if calling the method failed.
        if (pResult == NULL)
            printf("Calling the add method failed.\n");

        // Convert the result to a long from a Python object.
        //result = PyFloat_AsDouble(pResult);
        pT1 = PyTuple_GetItem(pResult, 0);
        pT2 = PyTuple_GetItem(pResult, 1);
        pT3 = PyTuple_GetItem(pResult, 2);

        // Convert output to float
        result1 = PyFloat_AsDouble(pT1);
        result2 = PyFloat_AsDouble(pT2);
        result3 = PyFloat_AsDouble(pT3);
        output_array[0] = result1;
        output_array[1] = result2;
        output_array[2] = result3;

        // Destroy the Python interpreter.
        Py_Finalize();

    }
```

And the Python module is defined as:

```
# module.py
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pickle
from sklearn.externals import joblib

def NN(a,b,c,):
    X_array = np.array([a, b, c])
    X = pd.DataFrame(X_array).transpose()
    clf = joblib.load('SavedNeuralNetwork.pkl')
    y = clf.predict(X)
    y = pd.DataFrame(y).transpose()
    y_array = pd.DataFrame.as_matrix(y)
    i = y_array.item(0) 
    j = y_array.item(1)
    k = y_array.item(2)
    output = (i, j, k)
    return i, j, k
```

At the first iteration the program works fine, but at the second iteration I get an unhandled exception at line:

```
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
```

And in particular:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00000001800db3ec in Fmain.exe: 0xC0000005: Access 
violation writing location 0x0000000000000002.
```

Why is this happening? I tried to reload the python module after the first iteration, but the same thing happened. Any suggestions or other comments on this are much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you initialize Python several times ? The first part of Call_NN should be put in an independent procedure called only once in the Fortran program.